# How do I get the output from an ASIO device to IceCast2 or FFMpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, live-streaming, icecast, jack

I have an ASIO device (Presonus Firestudio 2626). I am using it to mix and create different outputs on all of it's provided outputs (about 9 outputs like ADT1, ADT2). I need someway to stream these outputs using either IceCast or FFMpeg RTP.

One of the problems is that I have a restriction on using only a MAC or a Windows machine as my ASIO device does not provide drivers for ubuntu.

What are the ways that I can connect the ASIO device outputs to IceCast or FFMpeg?

I've tried the following.

Windows:
Jack - LiquidSoap - IceCast
Problem is that LiquidSoap on windows does not work with Jack.
Virtual Audio Cable - Butt - IceCast
Virtual Audio Cable was very inefficient. More than 2 streams and it crashes.

Mac:
Jack - DarkIce - IceCast
Jack doesn't work on Mac versions above Snow Leopard.

Can someone help me with which tools I should use and how I can do this?
I'm a complete novice on this so please provide some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edcast ASIO Standalone](http://dl.audioaddictz.com/Broadcast_Tools/oddsock_mirror/Compiled/Edcast/Moded_Versions/edcast-reborn/edcast_asio_3.37.2011.1214.exe) will work on Windows to allow streaming directly from your ASIO device or even JACK.

Note that Edcast hasn't been maintained in a long time, but it's still one of the best tools for streaming.  Here's a mirror of all downloads:

http://dl.audioaddictz.com/Broadcast_Tools/oddsock_mirror/Compiled/Edcast/Moded_Versions/edcast-reborn/

Comment: No. I can't access the channels of my ASIO device using this.
How do I use it with Jack?

Comment: @Saneet Why can't you?  Did you install the ASIO version?  To use it with JACK, install JACK and select the JACK Router ASIO device.