# Is it possible to capture audio from an ASIO device with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, windows-7-x64, asio

We have a setup with a Windows 7 machine where we installed Dante Virtual Soundcard and start that soundcard with ASIO capabilities. The soundcard will receive audio over the network from a Tesira server. We want to capture the audio to files (highly preferring each channel to a separate file). The files will be played back on a later moment. There will likely be 6 channels or more.

In the same setup we use ffmpeg to capture some video which is working fine, with Direct Show. So for audio we wanted to use the same setup, since ffmpeg is able to record audio as well. However, there seems to be no option to select the ASIO devices which the virtual soundcard probably creates. So the question is what command line to use for ffmpeg, or what to install? Or which other program can record ASIO from command line?

I already tried installing:

- Asio4all (actually wrong way around)
- sox (don't know why actually)
- HiFi Cable Asio Bridge (from VB-audio, not enough channels even with donate version)
- Voicemeeter (from VB-Audio, not enough channels and actually mixes down)
- O Deus Asio link, this might be an interesting option but it did not let me configure any route, any suggestions?

One thing I noticed is that the virtual soundcard can also be set to use WDM. Then I can see the devices with `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i duymmy`, but recording does not yield any result, I have to `ctrl-c` to make it stop instead of `q`, and the file is zero bytes. Supposedly this is because the data over the network is all ASIO formatted and the Tesira Server cannot send "WDM data". FFmpeg stops at selecting the capture pin for audio only

EDIT:

I ran ffmpeg with high verbosity and when selecting the WDM soundcard it stops at `Selecting pin Capture on audio only`. Also when requesting the options it gives the same line for 22 times: `min ch=1 bits=8 rate= 11025 max ch=2 bits=16 rate= 44100`

Comment: It turns out there might be something wrong with the setup as the ffmpeg trace logging plus looking in the code revealed that it is waiting for a packet (some sound), which it apparently doesn't get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: it is not possible to capture sound from an ASIO device with ffmpeg. Maybe I will write the code for it if I need it...

I could however solve my issues by separating the two streams of audio data we have (AVB and Dante). These where on the same switch and maybe it is a bug in the firmware, maybe misconfiguration.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[How do I get the output from an ASIO device to IceCast2 or FFMpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678442/how-do-i-get-the-output-from-an-asio-device-to-icecast2-or-ffmpeg)

Duplicate?

And if not, Place the output for `ffmpeg -f dshow -i "audio=your_device_name_in_dshow" -list_options`

Comment: It sure sounds like a duplicate, however I think Edcast is about streaming audio to the network/internet. Nevertheless I installed the program, and indeed the device is shown. But when executing the command line it gives error that device is not found

Comment: Furthermore it only allows to select one pair of channels, while I need more

Comment: And what about `-f show -list_options` ? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it said the device was not found (I used the name I got in Edcast)

Comment: So you say it is visible by `-list_devices` but when using with `-list_options` it said device is not found? I think it could not be so

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it showed the error when using the ASIO-name (from Edcast), when using the name from `-list_devices` (which is thus dshow) it gives the message as stated in the updated question post

Answer (score 0):

You might use Voicemeeter instead of HIFI-Cable / ASIO-Bridge. Voicemeeter is a virtual audio device mixer able to connect everything together, any audio point, in any interface and any app together (including ASIO DAW)... Download & User Manual on www.voicemeeter.com

Comment: Thanks, I tried this one, but it only has 2 channels while I need more (updated the question as well)

Comment: what do you mean by 2 channels ? Voicemeeter can handle 2 physical input devices (mono or stereo) and one virtual input (1 to 8 channels) ... Voicemeeter Banana version can manage 3 physical devices and 2 virtuals... let me know where is your limitation in your use case.

Comment: I could only select A and B, which I think are both stereo, so 4 channels in total (all my inputs are mono). But if I understand correctly, they are all mixed in to one stereo signal, and I really want them all apart so they can be mixed by end-user. Plus I have more then 4 signals, probably 6 or 8 (not hard-defined yet)

Comment: Voicemeeter BUS are 8 channels capable, but you might use BANANA version to get a better control (full mix minus feature for example).